# iOS updating from 6.1.3 to 7

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an iPad mini that I'm trying to update from 6.1.3 to 7 -- however, the iPad seems to say that I'm currently on the latest version. Why does this happen? Is there something I should be doing?

Answer (score 4):

iOS 7 is not yet publicly released yet. It is only available to developers. Unless you are a developer you can not yet update your device. 6.1.3 is the most current software so there is nothing wrong with your device. For more information regarding iOS 7 please follow this link: http://www.apple.com/ios/ios7/